# In a triangle counts: a : b = 3 : 4 and angle beta is 42 degrees-calculate the other angles

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

calculate the angles

I am strugling with this one, wouldnt i need to know what triangle it is or can it be done with just these informations? greatfull for any help.

If it has a right angle i can just use trigonometry and do it but if im not sure it has a right angle what can i do?

Comment: Use the law of sines.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503073